# It will be correctly identified vs It will correctly be identified

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverb-placement

I have two sentences 'It will correctly be identified as X.' and 'It will be correctly identified as X.' I was wondering is one of them incorrect grammatically perhaps? or do they both mean the same thing without grammatical issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both fine grammatically. Actually, I would tend to use a third form:

> It will be identified correctly as X.

But they all mean the same, and are all perfectly good English.

Answer (score -2):

Both are incorrect. **Until something is identified you cannot know what it will be.**

'It **will be** correctly identified" is a correct statement

'It **was** correctly identified as X.' is a correct statement

Comment: I disagree. The question is about grammar, not semantics. "The moon is made of green cheese." is false, but it's grammatically fine.

Comment: I can imagine a trial attorney arguing his case to the jury about a piece of evidence, saying, "It will be correctly identified as X by our next witness."

Comment: @tpk "The moon is made of green cheese." may be false but the grammar is correct "The Cheese moon will be mouldy green" is also correct.   However I have my suspicions that "The cheese moon will mouldy be green" is incorrect.